# Genetic Algorithm for finding the best path for a bot

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-physics, bots, genetic-algorithm

I have been recently coding on codingames.com. In that I came across few problem in which it seems we need to use genetic algorithm for finding the best path for my bot.
First I started up with basic if else statement algorithms, which was just fine to make me reach to the bronze league of the contest. But then this algorithm made me no good. I searched on net on how to go ahead, and most of the winners of the bot programming suggested that they used genetic algorithm for the purpose.
I searched on net about GA, and got to know that we start with a given population and then we do some crossover and mutation thing to find the fittest genes existing in the population.
But my question is that how to apply the logic in the bot designing where we have to decide the thrust given to the bot and the degree of turning for the bot.
Here is the link to the question - https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/coders-strike-back
I would be really glad if someone could send me not just the genes description for this problem as its already available on - https://www.codingame.com/blog/one-hour-learn-bot-programming/
I know the genes or genome which I may use. I want to know that how can I use it to predict my path. Would be glad if someone shares a pseudo code of how the algorithm works in this question.

Comment: Did you check the "External Resources" category (of Coders Strike Back)? There's more thorough material about the genetic algorithm approach there than anyone could describe in an answer here. [pb4601 post mortem](https://www.codingame.com/blog/en/2016/03/coders-strike-back-pb4608s-ai-rank-3rd.html) [Jeff06 post mortem](https://www.codingame.com/blog/en/2016/03/coders-strike-back-jeff06s-ai.html) [Magus post mortem](http://files.magusgeek.com/csb/csb_en.html)

Answer (score -1):

There is a `-3` velocity formula that will get you to your goal:

```
print nextcheckpointx-3*velocity, cextcheckpointy-3*velocity, 'BOOST'
```

Comment: why is this comment unworthy?